# Android AsyncTask: async-task for each viewpager fragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, android-handler

I have `viewpager` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. And I used `AsyncTask` in the `Fragment` because there is calculation process in the `Fragment`. These fragments will be loaded from `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Here is snap code from the fragment..

```
public void refreshView() {
        if(asynTask == null) {
            asynTask = new SetupTableTask();
        }
        asynTask.execute();
    }

    private class SetupTableTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            setupInitialValue();
            dashboradView.removeAllViews();
            setupTableRow();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Dashboard",
                    " Loading...", true, false);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I swipe 4 or 5 pages quickly. I got this exception.

```
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4607)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:835)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:292)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
08-07 10:48:36.366: E/AndroidRuntime(5702):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:292)
```

I would like to know can I use the AsyncTask in ViewPager's fragment. Any idea to overcome this exception? I have already tried the `Handler`. I got the same exception like `CalledFromWrongThreadException`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind or remove any kind of View  in `AsyncTask` `doInBackground` like

```
  dashboradView.removeAllViews();
```

remove it from `doInBackground`
and put in `onPostExecute` and  here you can bind your Views